# Having Issue while using Google Vision OCR API when hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, google-api, google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-vision

Getting below error while sending image to Google Api function

```
        //Load the image file into memory
        var image = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image.FromStream(uplFile.PostedFile.InputStream);


        // Instantiates a client
        var client = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();


        // Performs label detection on the image file
        var response = client.DetectDocumentText(image);
```

> Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Apis.Auth, Version=1.21.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

StackTrace: at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ChannelPool.d__5.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine) at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ChannelPool.CreateChannelCredentialsUncached() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke() at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at Google.Api.Gax.TaskExtensions.WaitWithUnwrappedExceptions(Task task) at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ChannelPool.GetChannel(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) at Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.ImageAnnotatorClient.Create(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ImageAnnotatorSettings settings) at.....

**package.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
<package id="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" version="11.0.1" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Google.Api.CommonProtos" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Google.Api.Gax" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Google.Api.Gax.Grpc" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Google.Apis" version="1.30.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Google.Apis.Auth" version="1.30.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Google.Apis.Core" version="1.30.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Google.Cloud.Vision.V1" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Google.Protobuf" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Grpc.Auth" version="1.7.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Grpc.Core" version="1.7.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" developmentDependency="true" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="System.Interactive.Async" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

**web.config**

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis.Auth" publicKeyToken="4b01fa6e34db77ab" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.34.0.0" newVersion="1.34.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices" publicKeyToken="4b01fa6e34db77ab" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.34.0.0" newVersion="1.34.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Protobuf" publicKeyToken="a7d26565bac4d604" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.6.0.0" newVersion="3.6.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Api.CommonProtos" publicKeyToken="3ec5ea7f18953e47" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Api.Gax" publicKeyToken="3ec5ea7f18953e47" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.4.0.0" newVersion="2.4.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Api.Gax.Grpc" publicKeyToken="3ec5ea7f18953e47" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.4.0.0" newVersion="2.4.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: -Same code works on local machine

Comment: -.Net framework used is 4.5

Comment: Please check whether Google.Apis.Auth.dll is present in the code deployed on the IIS

Comment: Yes..Google.Apis.Auth.dll is present with version 1.30.0 @IpsitGaur

Comment: But your Code is asking for version 1.21.0 as seen in the error, was the same version available in the local environment?

Comment: Same code works on local machine

Comment: When you say "when hosted in IIS" - do you mean "when hosted in Azure"? What about hosted in IIS but on the local machine? And your binding redirect is for 1.34.0 - if you've only got 1.30.0 present, that could be part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would check to see where you project file is looking for the DLL. You can find this by expanding dependencies in Visual Studio, right-clicking the Google.Apis.Auth dependency and selecting properties. My guess is that it is pointed at another copy of the DLL somewhere else on your machine that is not getting published. If that is the case, reinstalling via NuGet should do the trick (it will update the dependency reference in the project file). I would uninstall the package via NuGet, make sure it is removed from the dependencies list, then reinstall.

Second, try adding `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.30.0" newVersion="1.30.0" />` to your web.config file inside the `<dependentAssembly>` tag of the `Google.Apis.Auth` dependency. This tells the application that you are satisfying the dependency with a newer version than the project is actually looking for. The section should look like the below. See the documentation for `bindingRedirect` at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/bindingredirect-element).

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis.Auth" publicKeyToken="xxx" cultuer="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.30.0" newVersion="1.30.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis.Auth" publicKeyToken="4b01fa6e34db77ab" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.30.0.0" newVersion="1.30.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices" publicKeyToken="4b01fa6e34db77ab" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.30.0.0" newVersion="1.30.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>